# Ansible: recursively monitor state of servers and fire off other tasks once a server reports 'OK', while moniotring the remaining servers

Tags: asynchronous, ansible

I have below scenario, for which I've chosen to use Ansible to try and accomplish.

See output below of `ansible --version`

```
ansible [core 2.14.3]
  config file = /home/user/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

I need to actively monitor the 'state' of servers, and once a server is found to be 'OK' that specific server needs to continue with the next task.

The problem I am facing is that I'm using a 'role' that monitors the 'state' of the servers I parse it, and I can't fire off a role asynchronously so that monitoring of the servers can happen in the background.

The 'state' of each server recorded in a dictionary variable that I watch for in the following task, once one of the servers 'state' is found to be 'OK', it should run the next task, while monitoring continues for the remaining servers that are not yet in 'OK' state.

See below example:

Ansible folder and file structure:

```
"{{playbook_dir}}/testing/main.yaml"
"{{playbook_dir}}/roles/state/tasks/get.yaml"
/tmp/localhost.state
/tmp/127.0.0.1.state
/tmp/127.0.1.1.state
```

`"{{playbook_dir}}/testing/main.yaml"` is my 'main' playbook that I use to run my server actions tasks.
See contents of it below:

```yaml
---
- hosts: [localhost]
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    servers_state_files: {
      "localhost": "/tmp/localhost.state",
      "127.0.0.1": "/tmp/127.0.0.1.state",
      "127.0.1.1": "/tmp/127.0.1.1.state",
    }

  tasks:
    - name: "task 1 - get and monitor server/s state"
      include_role:
        name: state
        tasks_from: get.yaml
      vars:
        - server_names: "{{ servers_state_files.keys() }}"
      # async: 100
      # poll: 0
      register: get_server_state_task
    
    - name: "task 2 - do some actions on server/s that have an 'OK' state"
      debug:
        msg: "some action on server - {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ server_state_dict_ok.keys() }}"
      retries: 5
      delay: 10
      until: server_state_dict_ok[item].state == 'OK'
      when: server_state_dict_ok is defined
```

See contents of the '/tmp/<server>.state' files:

`/tmp/localhost.state`

```
OK
```

`/tmp/127.0.0.1.state`

```
ERROR
```

`/tmp/127.0.1.1.state`

```
PENDING
```

See contents below of: `"{{playbook_dir}}/roles/state/tasks/get.yaml"`

```yaml
---
- name: "open state file/s"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "server state file - {{ servers_state_files[item] }}"
      - "state - {{ lookup('file', servers_state_files[item]) }}"
  loop: "{{ server_names }}"
  when:
    - server_names is defined
    - servers_state_files is defined

- name: "set server state dictionary fact"
  set_fact:
    server_state_dict: "{{ server_state_dict | default({}) | combine( {item: {'state': lookup('file', servers_state_files[item])}} ) }}"
  loop: "{{ server_names }}"
  when: 
    - server_names is defined
    - servers_state_files is defined

- name: "show server_state_dict param"
  debug:
    msg: 
      - "server_state_dict - {{ server_state_dict }}"
  when: server_state_dict is defined

- name: "create server_state_dict_ok"
  set_fact:
    server_state_dict_ok: "{{ server_state_dict_ok | default({}) | combine( {item: {'state': lookup('file', servers_state_files[item])}} ) }}"
  with_items: "{{ server_state_dict.keys() }}"
  when: 
    - server_state_dict is defined
    - server_state_dict[item].state == 'OK'

- name: "Show server_state_dict_ok param"
  debug:
    msg: 
      - "server_state_dict_ok - {{ server_state_dict_ok }}"
  when: 
    - server_state_dict_ok is defined
    - server_state_dict_ok | length > 0

- name: "'Pop' keys from server_state_dict that have 'OK' state"
  set_fact:
    server_state_dict: "{{ server_state_dict | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=[item]) }}"
  with_items: "{{ server_state_dict }}"
  when: 
    - server_state_dict is defined
    - server_state_dict[item].state == 'OK'

- name: "Show server_state_dict param"
  debug:
    msg: 
      - "server_state_dict - {{ server_state_dict }}"
  when: 
    - server_state_dict is defined
    - server_state_dict | length > 0

- name: "Set and increment counter"
  set_fact:
    counter: "{{ counter | default(0) | int + 1 | int }}"
  when: 
    - server_state_dict is defined
    - server_state_dict | length > 0

- name: "Show counter param"
  debug:
    msg: 
      - "counter - {{ counter | int }}"
  when: 
    - counter is defined

- name: "Set a 'sleep' of 10 seconds to give the server/s a chance to have it's state changed to 'OK'"
  command: "sleep 10"
  when: 
    - server_state_dict is defined
    - server_state_dict | length > 0

- name: "Continue to monitor server/s state for servers whose state is not 'OK'"
  include_tasks: get.yaml
  vars:
    server_names: "{{ server_state_dict.keys() }}"
  when: 
    - server_state_dict is defined
    - server_state_dict | length > 0
    - counter | int <= 5
```

The `get.yaml` task will 'loop' itself (see the last task step where it includes itself) a maximum of 5 times because of the counter I set and check.

This all works fine and well, I however want to be able to run `get.yaml` asynchronously, so that as soon as a specific server's 'state' changes to 'OK', that server can continue with the next actions, i.e. `"task 2 - do some actions on server/s that have an 'OK' state"`.

This might not be the best approach, hence my question.

Your time and assistance with this is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't need gathered facts of the servers, there are outside factors (i.e. being added to HPE oneview) that's happening to the servers which is setting their 'state', and that changes depending on those 'outside' factors, hence the need to monitor their state with 'get.yaml'

Comment: Are those outside factors controlled by Ansible within the same run? Or are they completely independent? If it's the latter, how do you decide when to run the playbook?

Comment: The outside factors are controlled by ansible in a different role. And while that's running, I'd like to be able to monitor the 'state' set in those files for example, and once one of the servers reports 'OK' it should continue with the next tasks while the others continue to be monitored.

Answer (score 1):

> I however want to be able to run get.yaml asynchronously, so that as soon as a specific server's 'state' changes to 'OK', that server can continue with the next actions, i.e. "task 2 - do some actions on server/s that have an 'OK' state".
> This might not be the best approach, hence my question.

It seems like you're reinventing the built-in [async execution mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html), or [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) module, or [execution strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html), or all of them together.

> The outside factors are controlled by ansible in a different role. And while that's running, I'd like to be able to monitor the 'state' set in those files for example, and once one of the servers reports 'OK' it should continue with the next tasks while the others continue to be monitored.

That role should rather control the retries itself and [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) for the corresponding hosts instead of writing the state to custom files. And in general, Ansible already works almost like this by default - it runs a play in parallel for batches of multiple (5 by default) hosts simultaneously, then proceeds to the next task once all hosts are done, then proceeds to the next play. If you don't want the hosts to "synchronize" between the tasks, you can use simply use `free` strategy - for each host, Ansible will run the next task as soon as the previous one is finished on that host.